# Using rendered property with uibmodal throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When using rendered in my modal angular throws error on modal.results, saying modal is undefined. what am i doing wrong thanks in advance!!

I use querySelector to get the modal dialog so i can set properties dynamically which works quite well.. but can't get the result back from the selection

```
function showMyPopover(p) {           
        var modal = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/modals/customPopoverModal.html',
            controller: 'customPopoverController as vm',
            size: 'sm',
            animation: true,
            windowClass: 'level-modal',
            windowTopClass: 'ng-animate',
            resolve: {                   
               results: function () {
                    return vm.results;
               }
            }                
        }).rendered.then(function () {
            // Grab target element
            //var element = document.querySelector('#pid' + p),
            var element = $('#pid' + p);
            var ePosition = element.offset();
            var mLeft = 25;
            var mTop = 25;
            popModal = document.querySelector('.modal-dialog');

            // Set style 
            popModal.style.margin = 0;
            popModal.style.top = 0;
            popModal.style.left = 0;
            popModal.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            var oTop = ePosition.top;
            var oLeft = ePosition.left;
            popModal.style.top = oTop + mTop + "px";
            popModal.style.left = oLeft + mLeft  + "px";
        });
        modal.result.then(function (reply) {
            vm.action = reply.choice;                               
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few more searches on google... i found a post that mentioned $uibModalInstance, after a few trys i finally got my custom dialog to allow me to render and position it dynamically and return a result with out error..

I removed the .rendered from the code above and added it into here...

Note: p=17 is just a test value...so it knows where to set the modal.

```
  function activate() {          
        $('#one').focus();
        $uibModalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
            doPositioning();
        });
    }

    function doPositioning() {
        var p = 17;
        var element = $('#pid' + p);
        var ePosition = element.offset();
        var mLeft = 25;
        var mTop = 25;
        var popModal = $('.modal-dialog');
        var oTop = ePosition.top + mTop;
        var oLeft = ePosition.left + mLeft;

        // Set style
        popModal.css("margin","0");
        popModal.css("top", oTop + "px");
        popModal.css("left", oLeft + "px");          
    }
```